# How is a toolbar generate from this line?

Tags: html

I have this line `<div id="preview_map"></div>` in a code I'm working on. It generates a toolbar with many button on it and display a map. My goal is to add a new button to this toolbar but how am I suppose to do it knowing that they are generated by this line ? I used grep to try to find a JS function who could use this id to generate buttons but nothing at the moment.

```html
<div id="embedded_map" class="mrg-btm">
    <div id="preview_map"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The contents of the toolbar will be generated by javascript so somewhere in your javascript files lies the function responsible - nobody can identify that for you.

Comment: @RamRaider Yes I know, but if the function is link to js, isn't it supposed to  have something like document.getElementById ? Because when I grep it the only file with this line in it is in commentary.

Comment: it could easily use the class rather than the ID - or it could use sibling selectors. try looking for the class attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your application is dynamically generating elements with JavaScript.

Your code only shows a `<div>` element, this provides nothing to identify how the buttons are being generated.

Open your website on Chrome and click *Inspect Element*. Then go to sources and you should be able to view the JavaScript that is creating the page.

Alternatively you can search through your source code for the id `embedded_map`, and you should be able to see the JavaScript written to generate the buttons.